# How to read .txt files as n-dimentional numpy arrays in Python when there is no delimiter?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have the "map" below in the map_test.txt file.

..........
..........
...||||||.
........|.
||||||||..
..........
..........

There is no delimiter, just strings.

Now I would like to read this file into NumPy 2-dim array of **shape=(7,10)**.

For now i have this

```
with open("map_test.txt") as file:
    array2d = [[char for char in line.strip()] for line in file]
map_test = np.array(array2d)
map_test.shape
```

and the output is correct

```
(7, 10)
```

I was wondering, is there more efficient way to do this?
I tried with **numpy.loadtxt**, but then I had a problem with obtaining desirable shape.

Comment: `loadtxt` is plain python code like yours, so even if it worked it wouldn't be faster.  You have a specialized format.  Use what works and don't worry about a mythical 'efficiency'

Comment: @hpaulj thank you very much for such a quick answer

Comment: I guess you can just set the delimiter to `''` and it reads each character as a single number.

Comment: @anishtain4 Setting delimiter to `''` will cause `ValueError: empty separator`.